# Facing problem in blazor component while uploading a file

Tags: c#, blazor

I am using .net core 6. I created a MVC web application and used Blazor component.

I created a component named 'NewUser'.

```
@code {
   private ApplicationUsers userModel = new ApplicationUsers();
   private ApiResponseMasterData _response = new ApiResponseMasterData();
 
   private async Task HandleSignatureChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
   {
        //signature = (IFormFile)e.Value;
   }
}
```

Here's the razor code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
@using MODELS.DBModels;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Http;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@inject HttpClient http;
@inject IConfiguration Configuration;

<EditForm Model="@userModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleSubmit">
   <div class="custom-file">
         <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="ProfilePicture" @onchange="HandleProfilePictureChange">
                            </div>
</EditForm>
```

Problem: on `chageeventargs` I want to save the uploaded file to my local folder. I tried but I'm getting only the path.

Comment: Your method name does not match the handler specified in `@onchange`: please give us the right pieces of code.

Comment: The [core[ tag has nothing to do with .NET based frameworks. Make your choice: [.NET-Core], [.NET-6.0], [ASP.NET-Core-WebApi], [ASP.NET-Core-MVC] ...

Comment: Since you are allready using Blazor, use the official InputFile component.